# 10-Bulb Edison Chandelier

Tags: lamp

I'd like to make this chandelier:

[image]

But before I embark on this quest I've few questions.

1. Cleverly titled "edison chandelier", this thing has 10 incandescent bulbs so energy consumption will be over the board with approx: 10*60w=600w. More than half of my houses total consumption at any given moment. What can I replace this with? Are there economy version of these bulbs? Transparent LED imitation of edisons bulb or something?
2. How do I choose a wire?
3. How do I connect wires at the base?
4. What about using arduino with wifi shield to wirelessly shut of portions of the lamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search on eg
 diy edison chandelier led
you'll get many hits. Some may even be relevant.
 The main challenge is getting some thing that looks like a filament.

Bulbs offered are in the 2W - 10W range so your load is well down on incandescent.

As far as can be seen from [the photo here](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/575558624/Dimmable_LED_Edison_Bulb_Chandelier_Pear/showimage.html)

[image]

the  [Shenzhen Rayleich Optoelectronic Technology Co., Ltd.](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/575558624/Dimmable_LED_Edison_Bulb_Chandelier_Pear.html) will sell you bulbs in boxes of 100 that look quite good. Someone may sell them or similar in unspecified-on-your-profile country. What country are you in? 1000 Watt total house power usage sounds commendably low.

The following are all Asian wholesale, but give you some idea of what LED substitutes are available.

Also Alibaba - [Bulbs specifically for Edison chandalier](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/593402189/led_edison_bulb_chandelier.html)  but appearance uncertain

[And similar ...](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/634235341/led_edison_bulb_chandelier.html) with candle-flame-ish bulb shape. Hover over picture for larger image.

[And another](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/481164898/Dimmable_LED_Edison_Bulb_Chandelier_Pear.html) with closeup bulb detail. What that looks like when lit I know not.

[image]

---

If low voltage LED then  flexible 2 conductor "lamp cord" is fine. If bulbs are mains rate you need local advice.

Control of individual lamps - by Arduino or other means is simple. But that's a following stage.

Comment: +1, wow, I now want some of those fake filament LED bulbs!

Comment: -1 I didn't feel this answered the OP's question sufficiently with regards to "how do I wire it." Explaining how bulb power consumption factors into wire selection, and how Edison sockets can be connected/soldered would be good additions.